# Big Query disappearing preview after appending new data

Tags: row, google-bigquery

Scenario:

1. I Create a new table in Big Query with 5 rows.
2. I append another 5 rows from a new CSV file.
3. Load operation is successful and the data has been added to the Big Query table.
4. I open the table inside the web interface, and go to "Preview" it still shows only 5 rows.
5. I refresh the browser or log out and log back in.
6. The new preview is now visible, I can see the whole 10 rows.
7. I go to another table and come back to the previous table and now the new 5 rows have disappeared. I can only see the old 5 rows again.

Even using `SELECT * FROM 'mytable';` only shows the new rows until I close the preview, after that, only first 5 rows show up.

What could be causing this, is this intended?

Or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. Clearing the browser cache didn't work either.

Comment: This is a bug, I've seen others reporting that the Preview is not consistent pleas open an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: I see, thanks for the link.